# Rubocop for tabs

Tags: ruby, syntax, tabs, space, rubocop

We would like to use Rubocop to validate our ruby is syntaxicaly correct and follow basic code guidelines.

Appart from that we have this rule : we indent using tabs to allow anybody to decided how they want them to be rendered (display them like 2 or 4 spaces)

The problem is that rubocop seems designed to refuse tabs for indentation AT ALL.

How can we override all theses rules to be space complients ?

EDIT: I'm thinking of overriding this module https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/source_parser.rb to replace all tabs from my files by 2 spaces to create the illusion for the gem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I overrid this module https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/source_parser.rb
to replace all tabs from my files by 2 spaces to create the illusion for the gem...

Answer (score 11):

Add to your `.rubocop.yml`:

```
Style/Tab:
  Enabled: false
```

to disable the tabs rule.

You can write your own [custom cop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#custom-cops) to check proper indentation.

Comment: But for instance if I use a tab in front of "private" I will get an error that there is no indentation in front of it !

Comment: does it mean that I have to rewrite ALL the cop that use indentation ? if yes it's a LOT

Comment: Yeah... you are right. Ruby's indentation rules are actually quite accepted - two space indentation - no tabs. Perhaps rubocop is not the tool for you after all...

Answer (score 6):

As an evil unrepentant tab user, I ended up hacking it like so.  This diff for 0.32.1:

```
--- processed_source.rb.orig    2015-07-28 05:53:52.199418557 +0100
+++ processed_source.rb 2015-07-28 05:54:04.750420458 +0100
@@ -13,7 +13,7 @@
                 :parser_error, :raw_source

     def self.from_file(path)
-      file = File.read(path)
+      file = File.read(path).gsub(/^(\t+)/) {|m| '  ' * m.size }
       new(file, path)
     rescue
       abort("#{Rainbow('rubocop: No such file or directory').red} -- #{path}")
```

You should now blend in perfectly.  Bwahahaha.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest version, add this to your `.rubocop.yml` file:

```
Layout/Tab:
  Enabled: false
```

You can find all default options listed here:

https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/config/default.yml

And, the rule is defined here:

https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/blob/master/lib/rubocop/cop/layout/tab.rb

Answer (score 1):

Patience, my dear colleagues, hopefully [the PR into the Rubocop core](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/rubocop/pull/7867) to enable tabs indentation will be merged soon. For now you can create the following rb file somewhere in your project and require it when running rubocop.

```sh
rubocop [...] --require rubocop_tabs.rb
```

The rubocop_tabs.rb:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'rubocop'
require 'set'

RuboCop::ConfigLoader.default_configuration['Layout/Tab']['SupportedStyles'] = %w[tab space]
RuboCop::ConfigLoader.default_configuration['Layout/Tab']['EnforcedStyle'] = :space

module RuboCop
    module Cop
        module Layout
            class Tab < Cop
                include Alignment
                include RangeHelp
                include ConfigurableEnforcedStyle

                MSG = '%<type>s detected.'

                def investigate(processed_source)
                    str_ranges = string_literal_ranges(processed_source.ast)

                    processed_source.lines.each.with_index(1) do |line, lineno|
                        match = style == :tab ? line.match(/\A\s* +/) : line.match(/\A\t+/)
                        next unless match

                        range = source_range(processed_source.buffer, lineno, match.begin(0)...match.end(0))
                        next if in_string_literal?(str_ranges, range)

                        add_offense(range, location: range)
                    end
                end

                def autocorrect(range)
                    if style == :tab
                        lambda do |corrector|
                            corrector.replace(range, range.source.gsub(/\A\s+/) do |i|
                                "\t" * i.size
                            end)
                        end
                    else
                        lambda do |corrector|
                            spaces = ' ' * configured_indentation_width
                            corrector.replace(range, range.source.gsub(/\t/, spaces))
                        end
                    end
                end

                private

                def message(_node)
                    format(MSG, type: style == :tab ? 'Space' : 'Tab')
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Also add the following to your `.rubocop.yml`

```yaml
Layout/Tab:
  EnforcedStyle: tab
```

Answer (score 0):

## Latest (1.50.2) version answer

Use this in your .rubocop.yml:

```yaml
Layout/IndentationStyle:
    Enabled: false
```